# Help Visualizing the double integral

Tags: integration

I understand that the double integral is
[image]
However what confuses me is when I try to visualize why this formula only accounts for the region inside the bounds and not the whole rectangular region.
[image]

My guess is it has to do with one of the bounds being (x) but I have a hard time visualizing that. Could someone maybe give me the 2 variable analog to this equation of the single integral, and show how it only looks at points within the specified region
[image]

Comment: Consider your computation as the volume of some long parallelepipedic sticks with small square sections...

Comment: ... like here https://mathinsight.org/double_integral_introduction

Answer (score 1):

The formula in your first picture seems to refer to double integrals over rectangles only. But if you know how to integrate over a rectangle, you can define the double integral over a non-rectangular bounded set $M$ by taking a rectangle $D$ which contains $M$, setting
$$
g(x,y) =
\begin{cases}
f(x,y), & (x,y) \in M
,\\
0, & \text{otherwise}
,
\end{cases}
$$
and defining
$$
\iint_M f(x,y) \, dxdy := \iint_D g(x,y) \, dxdy
$$
(provided that the integral on the right-hand side exists).

Comment: I understand what your saying but I didn't get why the equation up above worked for defining the double integral in a way you can compute with out a computer

Answer (score 0):

[image]
The equation works for non rectangular regions because dy or dx can be a function of x and y itself meaning the height and width of your rectangles dydx changes based on were you evaluate your point, thus only accounting for the area inside the the region as n goes to infinty.

Answer (score 0):

To illustrate Hans' (+1) answer:

[image: Riemann sums for a non-rectangular plane region]

Extending the integrand by $0$ outside the triangle of integration gives us a function whose Riemann sums we can compute. The darker gray squares represent the contributions where the integrand is given by a piecewise formula (i.e., not by $f(x, y)$ or by $0$). The total contribution from these squares is negligible in the limit as the mesh of the partition goes to $0$.

As for the variable limits of integration, the terms of the Riemann sum where $x < y$ (i.e., the lighter-shaded squares) are zero. We can think of including those terms in the Riemann sum (because $f(x_{i}, y_{j}) = 0$), or we can omit those terms by summing only over the unshaded and darker-shaded squares. Either way, in the limit as the mesh decreases we obtain the stated iterated integral. For each $x$, the integral over $0 \leq y \leq x$ is approximated by the Riemann sum over the blue slice.